# How to get FormArrayName when the FormArray is nested in another FormArray?

Tags: arrays, forms, angular, nested, getter

Refering to : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArrayName-directive.html, it is easy to get a FormArrayName :

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="cities">
    <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i">
       <input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="City">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```ts
form = new FormGroup({
  cities: new FormArray([
    new FormControl('SF'),
    new FormControl('NY')
  ])
});

get cities(): FormArray { return this.form.get('cities') as FormArray; } 
// This does the magic!
```

The DOM `<div formArrayName="cities">`
uses the getter
`get cities(): FormArray { return this.form.get('cities') as FormArray; }` 
and everything is working like a charm

### BUT

How to make the getter when the FormArray is nested in another FormArray?

Let's say this example :

```ts
form = new FormGroup({
  cities: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({ 
      name: new FormControl('SF'),
      sisterCities: new FormArray(['Shanghai','Zurich',...])
    }),
    new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('NY'),
      sisterCities: new FormArray(['London','Oslo',...])
    }),
  ]),
});

get cities(): FormArray { return this.form.get('cities') as FormArray; } 
// still get the main cities FormArray

// but 
// get sisterCities() won't work because I need to target a city FormGroup (NY or SF) before accessing its sisterCities FormArray.
// and AFAIK, it is not possible to pass parameters to a getter.
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="cities">
    <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
       <input [formControlName]="name" placeholder="City">
       <div formArrayName="sisterCities"> <!-- this will never work -->
         <div *ngFor="let sisterCity of sisteCities.controls; index as j">
           ...
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please, help me to achieve this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have found a workaround : I do not use a FormNameArray neither a getter for the sisterCities, and use `*ngFor="let sisterCity of city.controls.sisterCities.controls` for my nested ngFor instead, but it does seem a bit ugly to me ...

Comment: another good solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527939/9583544 . Works like charm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem. And finally solved it.
Firstly we looking to main form array 'cities' structure.

[image: Nested FormArray structure]

Which is the yellow highlighted controls at image is the first array control path. => `cities`
And green highlighted control is the second array control. => `sisterCities`

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="cities">
    <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
       <input [formControlName]="name" placeholder="City">
       <div formArrayName="sisterCities"> <!-- this will never work -->
         <div *ngFor="let sisterCity of cities.controls[i]sisterCities.controls; index as j">
           ...
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Proper way to access this second nested FormArray is accessing first control array after insert current cities index. And respectively `sisterCities`,`control`.

```
let sisterCity of cities.controls[i].sisterCities.controls
```

Comment: Thx. I found the same workaround (as I explained in my comment). By the way, I think you are missing a dot in `cities.controls[i]sisterCities.controls` ==> `cities.controls[i].sisterCities.controls`

Comment: Yeah i forgot dot. I hope helps anyone this apporach.

Comment: I got an error "Property 'sisterCities' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'." But this way is working: `*ngFor="let sisterCity of cities.get('sisterCities').controls; let i=index"`

Comment: @Experimenter this answer written in 2017.  Angular continuously evolving. 
get function gets you AbstractControl, I guess what we want here.

Answer (score 3):

it worked like a charm for me same as nested form groups .. you need to:

1. use [formGroupName]="i"
2. formControlName cannot be dynamic .. instead it should have the name that you when you initialized the from group and there are countless example for that.
3. you need to iterate over the form array controls in the same div that you used formArrayName attribute in.

Comment: I'm working with dynamic `formControlName` and it's working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest and clear solution I found.

First let's consider below is our form structure

```
  this.empForm = this.fb.group({
          employees: this.fb.array([])
        });
    

 newEmployee(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      skills: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }
```

We have employee array and each employee has skills array.

So how do we access outer form array, it's simple function like below or you can have getter for the same

```
employees(): FormArray {
    return this.empForm.get('employees') as FormArray;
  }
```

This can be intergrate like below

```
<form [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="employees">
    <div *ngFor="let employee of employees().controls; let empIndex=index">
```

Now the complexity is in accessing inner formArray for that we need pass the index of formGroup and using that we can get the formArray, like below

```
employeeSkills(empIndex: number): FormArray {
    return this.employees()
      .at(empIndex)
      .get('skills') as FormArray;
  }
```

template part of this

```
<div formArrayName="skills">
          <div
            *ngFor="let skill of employeeSkills(empIndex).controls; let skillIndex=index"
          >
            <div [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
```

[Check here for full example....](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/nested-formarray-example-add-form-fields-dynamically/)