# Formarray inside formArray in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement formarray inside formarray but its not working, tried below too but doesn't work.

[How to get FormArrayName when the FormArray is nested in another FormArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428634/how-to-get-formarrayname-when-the-formarray-is-nested-in-another-formarray)

could someone please help me where am i doing wrong in below code

**HTML**

```html
<div [formGroup]="MainFormGroup" class="custom-auto-complete">
  <mat-radio-group matInput formControlName="Applies">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let applie of applies" [value]="applie.id">{{applie.value}}</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>           
  <div formArrayName="FormArrayOne">
    <div *ngFor="let mains of MainFormGroup.get('FormArrayOne')['controls']; let i=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="MainFormGroup.get('FormArrayOne').length > 1" (click)="removeMarket(i)">remove_circle</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon (click)="addOne()"> add_circle</mat-icon>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput formControlName="OneField" value="">
        </mat-form-field>
        <div formArrayName="FormArrayTwo">
          <div *ngFor="let Market of MainFormGroup.get('FormArrayTwo')['controls']; let j=index" >
            <div [formGroupName]="j">            
              <mat-form-field class="formfieldsControl">
                <input matInput formControlName="Destination">
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

**TS**

```js
public ngOnInit() {
  this.MaintFormGroup = this._fb.group({
    Applies : '',
    FormArrayOne: this._fb.array([
      this.initArrayOne(),
    ])
  });
}
public initArrayOne() {
  return this._fb.group({
    OneField: '',
    FormArrayTwo : this._fb.array([
      this.initFormArrayTwo()
    ])
  });
}
public addMarket() {
  const control = <FormArray> this.MaintFormGroup.get('FormArrayOne');
  control.push(this.initArrayOne());
}
public removeMarket(i: number) {
  const control = <FormArray> this.MaintFormGroup.get('FormArrayOne');
  control.removeAt(i);
}
public initFormArrayTwo() {
  return this._fb.group({
    Destination : ''
  });
}
public addFormArrayTwo() {
  const Control = <FormArray> this.MaintFormGroup.get('FormArrayTwo');
  Control.push(this.initFormArrayTwo());
}
public removeFormArrayTwo(j: number) {
  const Control = <FormArray> this.MaintFormGroup.get('FormArrayTwo');
  Control.removeAt(j);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[**This link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form) is more of a gist to the problem but you can take a look at this project i created on stackblitz which has deep nested forms .

Comment: I am getting this error if i run the code in my local @Rahul Singh

Comment: ERROR in c:/copa/deep/src/app/app.component.ts (62,60): Property 'controls' does
 not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
ERROR in c:/copa/deep/src/app/app.component.ts (92,61): Property 'controls' does
 not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Comment: renamed .control ==> [control]   working fine thanks

Comment: @user3419304 :)

Comment: Its seems your code has some bug, if u add three section and then add three options, now if we try to remove options of third its not working now able to remove

Comment: @user3419304 fixed it

Comment: Nice example. Thank you for that. But how do i fill that with data on init. Let's say with 3 sections and random numbers of options....
Thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks, it still working well today (Angular 10) :) Just need to cast the whole controls each times on functions `addQuestion`, `add` and `removeQuestion`.

Comment: if you type in some text into the inputs for question, as question 1 and then add another question as question 2.  the delete of q2 actually deletes q1.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thank you!