# Angular5 Reactive Forms: Form array inside another form array

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to add a `FormArray` inside another `FormArray` but can't figure out how to do it.

I have this in my typescript file:

```
createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        people: this.formBuilder.array([
            { addresses: this.formBuilder.array([]) }
        ])
    });
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to say make a people `FormArray` where each person can have multiple addresses. I try to render it like this in my html:

```
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formArrayName="people">
        <div *ngFor="let person of people.controls; let i=index">
            Person {{ i + 1 }}

            <div *ngFor="let address of person.addresses.controls; let j=index">
                Address {{ j + 1 }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, this is just an example and my actual form will have way more going on. I have an "Add person" link that calls a function in my typescript that pushes an object to the people `FormArray`.

When I call `createForm()`, I get the following errors in the browser:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
ERROR TypeError: this.form.get is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I accomplish what I want to do? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134068/formarray-inside-formarray-in-angular-4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try Something Like this:

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array)

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div formArrayName="people">
        <div *ngFor="let person of getPeople(myForm); let i=index">
            <div style="margin: 5px;" [formGroupName]="i">
                <label>Person {{ i + 1 }}</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
                <button *ngIf="i<1" (click)="addPeople()" type="button">Add People</button>

                <div formArrayName="addresses">
                    <div *ngFor="let address of getAddress(person); let j=index">
                        <div [formGroupName]="j">
                            <span>Address {{ j + 1 }}</span>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="house No" formControlName="houseNo">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="city" formControlName="city">
                            <button *ngIf="j<1" (click)="addAddress(i)" type="button">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
    {{myForm.value | json}}
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  survey: FormGroup;
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      people: this.fb.array([this.createPeopleArray()])
    })
  }

  createPeopleArray() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: null,
      addresses: new FormArray([
        this.createAddressArray()
      ])
    });
  }

  getPeople(form) {
    return form.controls.people.controls;
  }

  getAddress(form) {
    return form.controls.addresses.controls;
  }

  createAddressArray() {
    return this.fb.group({
      houseNo: null,
      city: null
    })
  }

  addPeople() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('people');
    control.push(this.createPeopleArray());
  }

  addAddress(i) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('people').controls[i].get('addresses');
    // console.log(control);
    control.push(this.createAddressArray());
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.myForm.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: @UnluckyAj I'm getting the following error: `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'people -> addresses'` using your code. Also, I noticed you have `addPeople(i)`, but your function doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: its working fine there is no issue in code and i removed 'i' addPeople(i) because no need for that.

Comment: Stackblitz link --> The page you requested couldn't be found.