# Unable to bind form with input ionic

Tags: html, angular, forms, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to bind my dynamic input fields with ionic html template.

**home.html**

```
    <form [formGroup]="clientForm">
     <ion-item *ngFor="let obj of clientForm.controls.assign_array.controls;let z=index">
            <ion-input placeholder="Type dat" type="text"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
    </form>
```

**home.ts**

```
constructor(){
 this.clientForm = this._fb.group({
   assign_array: this._fb.array([])
 });
}
```

**On save click:**

```
btnClick(){
    console.log("clintform--- " + JSON.stringify(this.clientForm.value));
}
```

**Output:**
        {
        "assign_array":[
        "",
        "",
        ""
        ]
        }

I can see multiple input fields in my app, but when i type something to each field my log doesn't show the value of `assign_array` fields

Where i am making mistake?

***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: What controls do assign_array contain?

Comment: only string it contains.

Comment: you need to set `formControlName` in ion input for reactive form to work

Comment: what object name to set on `formControlName` ?

Comment: depends on the controls in the array `this.clientForm = this._fb.group({
   assign_array: this._fb.array([])
 });`

Comment: Can you plz write a code so i can understand easily

Comment: Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436145/angular-reactive-forms-with-nested-form-arrays

Answer (score 0):

You have to just use `[(ngModel)]` in your `html` like this.

```
<ion-input placeholder="Type dat" type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputFieldValue"></ion-input>
```

and in `.ts` file

```
public inputFieldValue;
console.log("--------inputFieldValue-------",inputFieldValue)
```

Hope this can help you out.

Comment: OP is using reactive form not ngModel

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark a `formControlName` for your inputs, since you want string values, you can just use the index as formcontrolname, which you get from your iteration:

```
<form [formGroup]="clientForm">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let obj of clientForm.get('assign_array').controls; let z=index">
    <ion-input [formControlName]="z" placeholder="Type dat" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```