# Angular 7 Dynamic Creating form with ngFor and ngModel with validation (or ngFrom)

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a table like input form in Angular.

My current solution is like this:

html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="doSomething()">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>First Name</tr>
        <tr>Last Name</tr>
        <tr>Phone Number</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let person of team"></tr>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.first_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required></td>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.last_name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required></td>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.phone" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button (click)="addNewEntry()"></button>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

ts:

```
team : new Array()
addNewEntry(){
    this.team.push({
        'first_name':'',
        'last_name':'',
        'phone':null})
}

doSomething(){
};
```

However, if I do it this way, the 'required' validator does not work on clicking the Submit button.

I tried couple of ways:

1. instead of setting *[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"* , I tried *name='person:{{$index}}'*. Does not work.
2. Tried to set up a *ngForm* and instead of using *ngModel*, use *formControlName*. I can't figure out how to dynamically create *formControlName* and validate them.

May I ask if there is a way to get this done properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use Angular ReactiveFormsModule. ReactiveFormsModule support FormArray and will make it easy to perform validation and get the form item values.

For reference, check out:

1. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48527939/9194488

Comment: The links are really helpful, Thanks!